# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#deactivate (Couldn't find User with 'id'=)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

With my rails app I can successfully destroy, sign up and log in users but I can seem to deactivate them. I get this error every time: 
`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#deactivate (Couldn't find User with 'id'=)`

```
record = s.execute([id], self, connection).first
    unless record
      raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
    end
    record
  rescue RangeError
```

Here's the User controller:

```
def deactivate
 user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  if current_user.admin?
  user.deactivate_account!
  redirect_to users_path 
  else
   redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

The _user.html.erb view:

```
<li><%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
<%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.admin? && @user != current_user %>
<%=link_to "deactivate", deactivate_path(user_id: @user), method: :post, 
                                         data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}%> 
<% end %>
</li>
```

and the routes:

```
get 'password_resets/new'
get 'password_resets/edit'
root             'static_pages#home'
get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
post '/deactivate', to: "users#deactivate"
```

The logs are:

```
Rendered .../.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (9.0ms)
Rendered .../.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.9ms)
Rendered .../.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
Rendered .../.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.3ms)
Rendered .../.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (44.8ms)
```

What could be wrong? I'm assuming error is in the controller. I am following Michael Hartl tutorial, as I'm a beginner, but I'm also trying to implement thing by myself (like this one).

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace of your log?

Comment: I have included the logs.

Comment: I meant the stack trace. means, where you see the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#deactivate (Couldn't find User with 'id'=)` there should be an option of seeing full stack trace. I want to see that one. There should be the line numbers of where its failing exactly etc.

Comment: Ah, ok.. sorry: I pasted them here: http://pastie.org/10343107

Comment: great, this would help. Now, could you please post the full code of your `UsersController`?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastie.org/10343114

Comment: One more thing, could you please inspect the `params` hash inside the `deactivate` method? Just put this line in the beginning of the `deactivate` method: `puts params.inspect` and show me the output i.e. what we are getting inside the `params` hash.

Comment: I think, you have to use `id` but not `user_id` in your `deactivate` method. I updated my answer. Please try and let me know. Also, show me the `params` hash output.

Comment: I have putted them, but I don't know where to see them.

Comment: `puts PARAMS HASH: #{params.inspect} `
put this line in the beginning of your `deactivate` method. Then, try to deactivate the user. Then, go to your rails log and there you will see:
PARAMS HASH: . . . . `

Comment: I have putted them and try to deactivate user: nothing shows on the logs except for the previous logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should make this a `PUT` request rather than `POST` as it is updating the user record.

Here are the changes that I made to make this work:

Modified the route to `PUT` in your `routes.rb` file:

```
put 'deactivate/:id(.:format)', :to => 'users#deactivate', :as => :deactivate_user
```

You did not have the implementation for deactivate_account method for your User model. I did that. In your User model:

```
def deactivate_account
 update_attributes!(activated: false)
end
```

And, finally, changed the user partial like this:

```
<%=link_to "Deactivate", deactivate_user_path(user), method: :put%>
```

Comment: Now: `NoMethodError in UsersController#index undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: hmm, this is not correct yet. Could you post the full stack trace without this change?

Comment: Please look at my updated answer and let me know if that works now.

Comment: Also, can you push your project to github so that I can clone that locally and debug?

Comment: I have it on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/claucece/sample_app2. I also have it on githube as a privaterepo (but I'm not the owner). Tomorrow, I can give you access.

Comment: BTW, the branch is deactivate-activate.

Comment: I am used to github. Also, its late night so I will go to bed. Please give me github access tomorrow so that I can clone. I will test it locally tomorrow and let you know the updates.

Comment: Ok! Have good night and thank you! Tomorrow, I'll give you the access.

Comment: No problem. Talk to you tomorrow then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86675/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-sofia).

Comment: This is great! Thank you!